# Postgres inverted like optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, sql-like

I have a huge table `(code_item, filename_lk)`, which allow to recognize different filename for a same item, and I would like to have better performance on my query:

```
select * 
from table 
 where 'file_received_123.xls' like filename_lk;
```

`filename_lk` has values like `'file\_received%.xls'`,`'file\_%\_123.xls'`,...

It takes actually 1 second for each query, how can I optimize this?
Index doesn't work visibly because query is not:

```
filename_lk like 'file_received.xls'
```

Example:I have to match the same item for these kind of filenames received:
UPM_VM27_6_BADCATS_MAIN_968389.xls
UPM_VM27_6_BADCATS_MAIN_.xls
VM_27_6_BADCATS_MAIN_
so i have rows for this item with:
filename_lk='%VM27_6_BADCATS_MAIN_%'
filename_lk='%_968389.xls' (the number is an ID)

Comment: Please show sample data if possible.

Comment: Thks, I added some sample...